# Moving django apps into subfolder and url.py error

Tags: django, django-apps, django-settings

I have a question about putting django apps into "apps" subdirectory. I have the app called “faktura” in a project_root. I didn’t like the fact it lies there and I want to store all my apps under “apps” subdirectory.

So, I found out that I could extend python path to “apps” subdir, so after looking in the internet, I added this string to settings.py: sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "apps")). Then I added the app to INSTALLED_APPS like “faktura”. Everything worked smooth until I added url(r'^faktura/', include('faktura.urls')) to urls.py in the root. Since that, Django throws the error message “No module named faktura” full taceback is here: http://dpaste.com/737380/

What can be wrong here, why only urls.py can’t find the app? And does it can’t find this app if I added it to the PATH? I spent a morning trying to figure out what’s wrong and now I need your help.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know why the previous answer got -1 aside from maybe a few redundant lines that can be corrected. Anyway, I found a slightly different method that doesn't involve adding anything to the python path.

This is my final directory structure, I will explain in a moment:

```
mysite
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── myfirstapp
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

No matter if you have just created your project or if you want to move your apps, create the `apps` subdirectory that should contain your apps. The trick is to add an `__init__.py` to that directory.

```
mkdir apps
touch apps/__init__.py
```

Now you can move your existing apps into the `apps` subdirectory. If you would like to create a new one instead here are the commands:

```
python manage.py mysecondapp
mv mysecondapp apps/
```

**Warning: Don't be tempted to call `python manage.py ./apps/mysecondapp`. For some reason this deletes all other apps in that directory. I just lost a day of work this way.**

Next, you will need to fix a few imports. Your `settings.py` should be prefixed with `apps`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'apps.myfirstapp',
    'apps.mysecondapp'
)
```

Lastly, fix your project's `urls.py` to prefix `apps`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
  url(r'^myfirstapp', include('apps.myfirstapp.urls')),
  ...
)
```

Depending on how you wrote them, you might also have to fix a few imports inside your app. Either just use `from models import MyFirstModel` or also prefix it using `from apps.myfirstapp.models import MyFirstModel`.

In short, if you make your `apps` directory a python package (by adding `__init__.py`), you can use it as part of the import path. This should work regardless of the deployment method with no extra configuration.

Comment: I ran into a problem that wasn't addressed in this answer, in that the urls.py in apps/myfirstapp needed to have the first argument of patterns(...) set to 'apps.myfirstapp', as before I moved it, it read only 'myfirstapp'.  Django's debug output was much less than helpful for this.

Comment: from apps.myfirstapp.models import MyFirstModel not working in the secondapps models file..don't know why..

Comment: Note that you **can't** use `apps.myfirstapp.apps.MyfirstappConfig` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Why we cannot use `Config`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `BASE_DIR` variable from the `settings.py`. It should be already defined:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Better not use the `__file__` attribute in `manage.py` and `wsgi.py`, as they are located in different directories.

So, just add the following to `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` (and to the `celery.py` if you use Celery):

```
    from django.conf import settings
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "apps"))
```

You will end up with the following project structure:

```
project
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   └── app2
└── manage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep your Django applications in a subfolder (such as apps/), first add the following to your settings.py:

`import os`

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Then in manage.py:

Right under #!/usr/bin/env python add:

`import sys`

`from os.path import abspath, dirname, join`

`from site import addsitedir`

Right before if __name__ == "__main__" : add:

`sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))`

Comment: Yep this works... but if you use - like I do - uwsgi as a app server then you should ALSO apply the insert into the wsgi.py file.

Comment: Do you really need the unused imports (addsitedir, dirname, abspath)? Or are they left over from a previous version of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Radu Gheorghiu's answer; It is not necessary to edit settings.py, and the insert path line can be condensed to 1 line of code.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "apps"))
```

I sourced this answer from http://obroll.com/nested-application-inside-apps-sub-folder-in-django-1-3/

Comment: Please do not create an answer on an answer. If you want to add something to Radu's answer, use the comment function.